# Is there a way to use an async check function for discord.py wait_for()?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I would like to use an async check function:

```
async def check(reaction, user):
   await x
   return y

await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

This yields an error message that says the check function isn't awaited:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.boost' raised an error: SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

If I change the code to:

```
async def check(reaction, user):
   await x
   return y
await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=await check)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Is there any way to have an async check function? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you remove the information about this being discord API? The question makes no sense without it.

Comment: this post is tagged discord.py and discord.py is in the title

Comment: That's because I reverted your edit from yesterday which removed the tags and the mention in the title....

Answer (score 2):

```
    async def predicate(ctx):
        # you can use any async code here
        result = await stuff()
        return result
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Just add async in from to use await features..

Also when you call the function  use Await in front

r = await predicate()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as an example to write an async check:

```
def mycheck():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        # you can use any async code here
        result = await stuff()
        return result
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

More information can be found here: [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/commands.html#checks)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import asyncio
@...
async def your_command(ctx, ...):

    async def run():
        # you can use await there
        return ...


    def check(msg):
        result = asyncio.create_task(run()) # run the async function
        return resul

    ctx = self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

and there is an example:

```py
import asyncio

@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):

    async def run(msg):
        await msg.send("This message is not yours!", hidden=True)
        return


    def check(msg):

        if msg.author.id == ctx.author.id:
            return True
        else:
            asyncio.create_task(run(msg))
            return False

    ctx = await self.bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check)

    ...
```

This work for me